# Как сделать анимацию canvas?

Tags: анимация, canvas

подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такую анимацию на сайте с текстом?

ссылка на видео с анимацией- https://disk.yandex.ru/i/lynvqyfIOBe43A

ссылка на сайт с примером анимации на главном экране : https://postfamiliar.com/

картинка с примером анимации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.